# Is there a way to log every request in the console with restify?

Tags: node.js, express, restify

I'm using `restify` to build an API, and I'm used to `express`. Is there a way to have `restify` log every request in the console, like `express` does with `app.use(express.logger('dev'))`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a very bare bones Restify/Bunyan example that will log every request:

```
'use strict';

var Logger = require('bunyan'),
    restify = require('restify'),
    log = new Logger.createLogger({
        name: 'app-name',
        serializers: {
            req: Logger.stdSerializers.req
        }
    }),
    server = restify.createServer({
        name: 'app-name',
        version: '0.1.0',
        log: log
    });

server.pre(function (request, response, next) {
    request.log.info({ req: request }, 'REQUEST');
    next();
});

server.get('/', function (request, response, next) {
    response.send('It worked!');
    next();
});

server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

The key to this is the `server.pre()` call.

Start it up in one terminal window and do a curl request in another terminal window.  You will see the response that it worked, and a log entry for the request.

Assuming a few things:

- You have a package.json file that will install bunyan and restify
- You put the code above in a file named `server.js`

You would do/see the following:

*Terminal Window 1*

```
$ node server.js
app-name listening at http://0.0.0.0:8080
{"name":"app-name","hostname":"leeloo.local","pid":97387,"level":30,"req":{"method":"GET","url":"/","headers":{"user-agent":"curl/7.30.0","host":"localhost:8080","accept":"*/*"},"remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":60870},"msg":"REQUEST","time":"2014-04-21T17:55:52.487Z","v":0}
```

*Terminal Window 2*

```
$ curl localhost:8080/
"It worked!"
```

If anyone would like to see my `package.json` I can put all of this up in a gist.

Comment: What if you wanted to edit the contents of request? Eg. if you wanted to remove some insecure information before logging it.

Answer (score 15):

You could also use the [Morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) logger middleware used in Express. Since Restify intentionally borrows heavily from Express, configure it is exactly the same.

This is how the [Usage server example](https://github.com/restify/node-restify) gets:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var logger  = require('morgan')

var server = restify.createServer({
  name: 'myapp',
  version: '1.0.0'
});

server.use(logger('dev'));
server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

server.get('/echo/:name', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send(req.params);
  return next();
});

server.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

Getting like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In reference to using **RequestLogger**, see this comment in [the docs](http://restify.com/#requestlogger):

> "This plugin does *not* log each individual request. Use the Audit Logging plugin or a custom middleware for that use."

#### Audit Logging ([docs](http://restify.com/#audit-logging))

> Audit logging is a special plugin, as you don't use it with .use(), but with the after event:

```
server.on('after', restify.auditLogger({
  log: bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'audit',
    stream: process.stdout
  })
}));
```

Comment: This is the way to go IMO. I would just add that you pass the `body: true` option to the auditLogger so you get to see the body of both the request and response in the logs. Very helpful. `server.on('after', restify.auditLogger({ log: log.logger, body: true }));`;

Answer (score 0):

By default `restify` uses [Bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) logger. From restify documentation

> **RequestLogger** Sets up a child bunyan logger with the current request
>   id filled in, along with any other parameters you define.

```
    server.use(restify.requestLogger({
        properties: {
            foo: 'bar'
        },
        serializers: {...}
    }));
```

> You can pass in no options to this, in which case only the request id will be appended, and no serializers appended (this is also
>   the most performant); the logger created at server creation time will
>   be used as the parent logger.

Comment: It didn't seem very straight forward ... I probably missed something but never got to get it working yet. So I switched to express...

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick way to do it very quickly if you just want to have it for your development environment.

```
/**
 * Log requests.
 */
server.on('after', function(req, res, route, error) {
    console.log("------------------------")
    console.log(req.route.path)
    console.log(req.body)
});
```

Answer (score -5):

I wrote something to do this. It's still being developed, but it seems to work so far. npm install restify-dev-logger, then

```
var logger = require("restify-dev-logger");
var restify = require("restify");
var srv = restify.createServer(...);
srv.use(logger.dev);
```

Or something like that. There's also logger.devbw, which doesn't have pretty terminal colors.

UPDATE: My package is broken (not sure why), but a workable replacement is here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/restify/iLRiYz3Fko0

Comment: Please be far more clear as to what you mean with "Or something like that."

Comment: As in "Your code will probably be somewhat different." I really don't see how this is unclear, but ask away if you don't understand.

Comment: Ignore this, it's broken